# An exception in Argparse

Tags: python, arguments

I have the following code for reading the arguments from a file and process them using argparse, but I am getting an error, why is this the case?

```
import argparse
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
import shlex

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Short sample app',
                                 fromfile_prefix_chars='@')

parser.add_argument('--abool', action="store_true", default=False)
parser.add_argument('--bunit', action="store", dest="bunit",type=int)
parser.add_argument('--cpath', action="store", dest="c", type=str)

print parser.parse_args(['@argparse_fromfile_prefix_chars.txt']) #name of the file is argparse_fromfile_prefix_chars.txt
```

Error:

```
usage: -c [-h] [--abool] [--bunit BUNIT] [--cpath C]
-c: error: unrecognized arguments: --bunit 289 --cpath /path/to/file.txt
To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

Contents of the file argparse_fromfile_prefix_chars.txt

```
--abool
--bunit 289
--cpath /path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` expects arguments from files to be one per line. Meaning the whole line is one quoted argument. So your current args file is interpreted as

```
python a.py '--abool' '--bunit 289' '--cpath /path/to/file.txt'
```

which causes the error. Instead, your args file should look like this

```
--abool
--bunit
289
--cpath
/path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: Or his file could have these three lines: `--abool`, `--bunit=289`, `--cpath=/path/to/file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`fromfile_prefix_chars`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars) states:

> **Arguments read from a file must by default be one per line** (but see
>   also [`convert_arg_line_to_args()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args)) and are treated as if they were in
>   the same place as the original file referencing argument on the
>   command line.

Note that *one argument* does **not** mean one *option followed by all its arguments*. It means a command line argument. Currently the whole lines are interpreted as if they were a single argument.

In other words your file should look like:

```
--abool
--bunit
289
--cpath
/path/to/file.txt
```

Alternatively you can override the [`convert_arg_line_to_args()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args) method to parse the file in an other way. The documentation already provides an implementation that parses white-space separated arguments instead of line-separated arguments:

```
def convert_arg_line_to_args(self, arg_line):
    # consider using shlex.split() instead of arg_line.split()
    for arg in arg_line.split():
        if not arg.strip():
            continue
        yield arg
```

I believe you can either subclass `ArgumentParser` and reimplement this method, or, probably, even setting the attribute on an `ArgumentParser` instance should work.

---

For some reason the default implementation of `convert_arg_line_to_args` doesn't work properly:

```
$echo '--abool           
--bunit
289
--cpath
/here/is/a/path
' > file.txt
$cat test_argparse.py 
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('--abool', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--bunit', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--cpath')


print(parser.parse_args(['@file.txt']))
$python test_argparse.py 
usage: test_argparse.py [-h] [--abool] [--bunit BUNIT] [--cpath CPATH]
test_argparse.py: error: unrecognized arguments:
```

However if you use the implementation above it works:

```
$cat test_argparse.py    
import argparse

def convert_arg_line_to_args(arg_line):
    for arg in arg_line.split():
        if not arg.strip():
            continue
        yield arg.strip()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('--abool', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--bunit', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--cpath')
parser.convert_arg_line_to_args = convert_arg_line_to_args

print(parser.parse_args(['@file.txt']))
$python test_argparse.py 
Namespace(abool=True, bunit=289, cpath='/here/is/a/path')
```

An other workaround is to use the `--option=argument` syntax:

```
--abool
--bunit=289
--cpath=/the/path/to/file.txt
```

However this will not work when an option has more than one argument. In such a case you have to use a different implementation of `convert_arg_line_to_args`.

---

Trying to debug, it seems like the `convert_line_arg_to_args` gets called with an empty string which gets added to the arguments, and the empty string is considered an argument (which isn't defined).

The problem is that there are *two* newlines at the end of the file.
In fact if you create the file without this double newline at the end, it works:

```
$echo -n '--abool
--bunit
289
--cpath
/here/is/a/path
' > file.txt
$python test_argparse.py 
Namespace(abool=True, bunit=289, cpath='/here/is/a/path')
```

(`echo -n` doesn't add a newline at the end of the output).

Comment: @Lanc For some reason the default implementation of `convert_arg_line_to_args` doesn't work properly. If you use the example implementation in my answer it works.

Comment: @Lanc Note that having more than one newline at the end of the output is a problem. See the updated answer.